# XNA 3.1 Movement Collision Issue

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics, collision

So heres my problem. I have a box that I want my character to move around. But I want to be able to move around it while holding multiple move commands, for instance..
when moving right (towards the left of the obstacle) I want to be able to hold move right and up or down at the same time without the character sticking to the box. The funny part is, it works fine for the left and right side of the obstacle, yet it sticks when i try it on the top and bottom side of the obstacle.
Heres the Player Class (object im moving)

```
<!-- language: c# -->
    public class Player
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public int speed;
    public Vector2 offset;
    public bool left, right, up, down;
    public Rectangle collisionRect
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)position.X , (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
        }
    }
    public Vector2 direction;
    public Player(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, int speed)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.position = position;
        this.speed = speed;
        offset.X = speed;
        offset.Y = speed;
        left = false;
        right = false;
        up = false;
        down = false;
    }
    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
    {
        direction = Vector2.Zero;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            direction.X -= 1;
            left = true;
        }
        else
            left = false;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            direction.X += 1;
            right = true;
        }
        else
            right = false;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            direction.Y -= 1;
            up = true;
        }
        else
            up = false;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            direction.Y += 1;
            down = true;
        }
        else
            down = false;

        position += (direction * speed);
    }
    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        spritebatch.Draw(texture, collisionRect, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Heres the Update Method in my maingame

```
    <!-- language: c# -->
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here
        player.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds);

        if (player.right && HitWall(player))
        {
            player.position.X -= player.offset.X;
        }
        else if (player.left && HitWall(player))
        {
            player.position.X += player.offset.X;
        }
        if (player.down && HitWall(player))
        {
            player.position.Y -= player.offset.Y;
        }
        else if (player.up && HitWall(player))
        {
            player.position.Y += player.offset.Y;
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

And the HitWall function

```
    <!-- language: c# -->
    public bool HitWall(Player player)
    {
        for (int i = player.collisionRect.Top; i < player.collisionRect.Bottom; i++)
            for (int j = player.collisionRect.Left; j < player.collisionRect.Right; j++)
                if (TextureData[i * gameMap.map.Width + j] != Color.White)
                    return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where offset is defined, but I'm assuming it's the movement you've just made that frame.

Your problem is that because you check left & right before up and down, if you're moving diagonally down onto the top edge of the box, then you'll register a hit in the Y direction — `HitWall` doesn't check which direction you're going, it just checks for a collision. Therefore, the collision in the Y axis stil counts on the line `if (player.right && HitWall(player))` and stops your lateral movement.

Best bet is to apply your sideways movement, check for a hit, move back if there is one — then apply your downwards movement, check for a hit, and move back if there is one. Correcting the position like this should mean you slide along the sides as you want.

Comment: thanks, what i did to fix it was make a bool for the first part(lateral), and when the vertical movement was being handled i just turned off the lateral checking.